# What is the best or recommended way to upload an image into db in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an application which will store some entities which have name, price, and an associated image into the database? The image will be a byte field?

I googled around, most examples involve upload image into server, and store the file path name into the db, is this the recommended way to do this? From my persptive, it seems make more sense to store the image byte array into db?

Will you be able to give me some hint or point some link online to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this post;

[Controller Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055567/having-troubles-calling-a-controller-post-method/1055998#1055998)

If this does not help then leave a comment and I'll be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in Image field if you use MS SQL, in MySQL you store it as Blob.

Comment: And yeah, it is a byte[] in both cases.