# How to bind uploaded files to IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> property

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

This the html form:

```
<input id="picture1" name="Input_Pictures" type="file" value="" />
<input id="picture2" name="Input_Pictures" type="file" value="" />
<input id="picture3" name="Input_Pictures" type="file" value="" />
```

I also tried:

```
<input id="picture1" name="Input_Pictures[]" type="file" value="" />
<input id="picture2" name="Input_Pictures[]" type="file" value="" />
<input id="picture3" name="Input_Pictures[]" type="file" value="" />
```

and also too:

```
<input id="picture1" name="Input_Pictures[0]" type="file" value="" />
<input id="picture2" name="Input_Pictures[1]" type="file" value="" />
<input id="picture3" name="Input_Pictures[2]" type="file" value="" />
```

This is my view model:

```
public class PicturesInputViewModel
{
     public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Pictures { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the submit action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(PicturesInputViewModel input)      
{
```

I **can** see the files in `Request.Files` collection, but `Pictures` is always null.

**How can I solve this binding problem?**

---

For the mean time I using this code successfully:

```
 var pics = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
 foreach (string name in Request.Files)
 {
     var file = Request.Files[name];
         if (file.ContentLength > 0)
             pics.Add(file);        
 }
 input.Pictures = pics;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give your controls different names: 
`Picture[1], Picture[2], .. , Picture[n]`.
Binder cannot decide that picture2 must be in Pictures collection.

Sorry, MVC doesn't have binder for collections of files.
You can use FileCollectionModelBinder from [MvcFutures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24471) project.
All you have to do is to reference MVCFutures assembly and add additional model binder (in global.asax.cs or elsewhere):

```
FileCollectionModelBinder.RegisterBinder(ModelBinders.Binders);
```

Comment: sorry, i meant Pictures[n], not Picture[n]

Answer (score -2):

Check out this post [Having troubles calling a Controller Post Method…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055567/having-troubles-calling-a-controller-post-method/1055998#1055998)

This might give you a clue as to how to fix your issue.

Comment: This is not giving a clue to the binding issue.