# Image Upload, Conversion Error InputStream.Read() method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload an image, using HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream.Read() method read the upload stream to a buffer, but it gives me a conversion error at

file.InputStream.Read(imageSize, 0, file.ContentLength);

please find the code below, am i missing something

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Upload Image</legend>

            @Html.Label("Title")
            @Html.Editor("fileTitle")<br />
            Upload File: <input type="file" name="test" />
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(string fileTitle)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
                    byte[] imageSize = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    **file.InputStream.Read(imageSize, 0, file.ContentLength);**
                    Image image = new Image()
                    {
                        Name = file.FileName.Split('\\').Last(),
                        Size = file.ContentLength,
                        Title = fileTitle,
                        ID = 1,
                        Image1 = imageSize
                    };
                    db.Images.AddObject(image);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Detail");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("uploadError", e);
                }
                return View();
            }
```

Comment: I think something is wrong at this line, ****file.InputStream.Read(imageSize, 0, file.ContentLength);**** the vs debugger breaks here

Comment: maybe this can be of some help (getting the file by its name instead of 0, not coercing the file type) http://stackoverflow.com/q/1055567/1236044

Comment: What kind of exception do you get? I tried out the code but there wasn't any exception.

Comment: i found this on microsoft, file.InputStream.Read(imageSize, 0, (int)file.ContentLength);

Comment: file.ContentLength has to converted to an int, and it does fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Upload Image</legend>

            @Html.Label("Title")
            @Html.Editor("fileTitle")<br />
            Upload File: <input type="file" name="test" />
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(string fileTitle)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
                    byte[] imageSize = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    ***file.InputStream.Read(imageSize, 0, (int)file.ContentLength);***
                    Image image = new Image()
                    {
                        Name = file.FileName.Split('\\').Last(),
                        Size = file.ContentLength,
                        Title = fileTitle,
                        ID = 1,
                        Image1 = imageSize
                    };
                    db.Images.AddObject(image);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Detail");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("uploadError", e);
                }
                return View();
            }
```